# Creating linux user password automatically with CloudFormation

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation to create an EC2 Linux machine which I can RDP into. I am running the required install commands as so:

```
"Metadata" : {
            "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {
                    "commands" : {
                        "step_a" : {
                             "command" : "install some stuff..."
                        },
                        "step_g" : {
                            "command" : "sudo yum groupinstall \"Gnome Desktop\" -y"
                        },
                        "step_h" : {
                            "command" : "sudo passwd centos"
                        },
                        "step_i" : {
                            "command" : "configure firewall to allow rdp..."
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see though, in step_h, I want to set a password for the default centos user. How can I automatically return a default password value when user input is required? Maybe there is a better way of going about this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of setting user password without prompt. Some of them can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190805/how-can-i-update-a-password-without-entering-the-password-twice) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80444/how-to-set-user-passwords-using-passwd-without-a-prompt) for examples.

However, the potential issue to consider is how are you going to provide this password in the template? Hardcode it in plain text? This is **security issue**. Pass it as a template parameter with `NoEcho`? This is better but not reproducible and prone to mistakes. Use SSM parameter store or AWS Secretes Manager? This would be probably best option but requires extra settings.